# Plot several Y axes

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to plot several Y axes, with different scales, here is my solution based on exemples I found on the web, but it only creates one extra Y axis, even I have more than that in my data.

```
        fig, ax = plt.subplots()
        plt.subplots_adjust(right=0.75)

        x, y, c, m, l = self.mData[0]
        ax.plot(x, y, color=c)
        ax.set_ylabel(l, color=c)
        for tl in ax.get_yticklabels():
            tl.set_color(c)

        ax.set_xlabel('time')

        for i in range(1, len(self.mData)):
            ax_other = ax.twinx()
            if i == 1:
                offset = 0
            else:
                offset = 60 * (i - 1)

            ax_other.set_frame_on(True)
            ax_other.patch.set_visible(False)
            ax_other.yaxis.set_label_position('right')
            ax_other.yaxis.set_ticks_position('right')
            ax_other.spines['right'].set_position(('outward', offset))

            x, y, c, m, l = self.mData[i]
            ax_other.plot(x, y, color=c)

            ax_other.set_ylabel(l, color=c)
            for tl in ax_other.get_yticklabels():
                tl.set_color(c)

        plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
```

In the code I plot the first set of data, then if there are other set to be plotted I create a new axis for each set.
The X axis displays dates, that are the same for each set of data that I can have.
And the problem with this code is that it only displays 1 of the extra axis I have.

mData is a list of namedtuples :

```
data_tuple = namedtuple('Data', ['x', 'y', 'color', 'marker', 'label'])
```

Where x is a list of datetime object, y is a list of float, color, marker and label are string.

```
Data(x=[datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 1, 0, 0, 25, 135000), datetime.datetime(2011, 2, 1, 0, 0, 57, 386000), datetime.datetime(2011, 3, 1, 0, 0, 59, 579000), datetime.datetime(2011, 4, 1, 0, 0, 27, 676000), datetime.datetime(2011, 5, 1, 0, 0, 25, 135000), datetime.datetime(2011, 6, 1, 0, 0, 26, 414000), datetime.datetime(2011, 7, 1, 0, 0, 28, 145000), datetime.datetime(2011, 8, 1, 0, 0, 26, 432000), datetime.datetime(2011, 9, 1, 0, 0, 27, 301000), datetime.datetime(2011, 10, 1, 0, 0, 27, 643000), datetime.datetime(2011, 11, 1, 0, 0, 27, 673000), datetime.datetime(2011, 12, 1, 0, 0, 28, 294000)], y=[-10.246537396121893, 1.3039215686274515, 1.007462686567164, -0.12771084337349403, -0.1932367149758454, -0.3196125907990315, -0.04128440366972498, -0.19950738916256117, -1.6319018404907975, -1.1532258064516134, -1.666666666666668, -2.3958333333333326], color='Red', marker='x', label='Mean')
Data(x=[datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 1, 0, 0, 25, 135000), datetime.datetime(2011, 2, 1, 0, 0, 57, 386000), datetime.datetime(2011, 3, 1, 0, 0, 59, 579000), datetime.datetime(2011, 4, 1, 0, 0, 27, 676000), datetime.datetime(2011, 5, 1, 0, 0, 25, 135000), datetime.datetime(2011, 6, 1, 0, 0, 26, 414000), datetime.datetime(2011, 7, 1, 0, 0, 28, 145000), datetime.datetime(2011, 8, 1, 0, 0, 26, 432000), datetime.datetime(2011, 9, 1, 0, 0, 27, 301000), datetime.datetime(2011, 10, 1, 0, 0, 27, 643000), datetime.datetime(2011, 11, 1, 0, 0, 27, 673000), datetime.datetime(2011, 12, 1, 0, 0, 28, 294000)], y=[-8.0, 19.0, 11.0, 6.0, 6.0, 6.0, 6.0, 6.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0], color='Red', marker='x', label='Max')
Data(x=[datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 1, 0, 0, 25, 135000), datetime.datetime(2011, 2, 1, 0, 0, 57, 386000), datetime.datetime(2011, 3, 1, 0, 0, 59, 579000), datetime.datetime(2011, 4, 1, 0, 0, 27, 676000), datetime.datetime(2011, 5, 1, 0, 0, 25, 135000), datetime.datetime(2011, 6, 1, 0, 0, 26, 414000), datetime.datetime(2011, 7, 1, 0, 0, 28, 145000), datetime.datetime(2011, 8, 1, 0, 0, 26, 432000), datetime.datetime(2011, 9, 1, 0, 0, 27, 301000), datetime.datetime(2011, 10, 1, 0, 0, 27, 643000), datetime.datetime(2011, 11, 1, 0, 0, 27, 673000), datetime.datetime(2011, 12, 1, 0, 0, 28, 294000)], y=[-12.0, -7.0, -6.0, -6.0, -6.0, -6.0, -6.0, -6.0, -6.0, -6.0, -7.0, -7.0], color='Yellow', marker='o', label='Min')
```

Comment: Is [this](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/finance_work2.html) the sort of thing you're trying to do?

Comment: No it is more like http://matplotlib.org/examples/axes_grid/demo_parasite_axes2.html, but with date formatting in the x axis.

Comment: OK, so have you tried using `mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.host_subplot` as shown in that example?

Comment: I tried but, can't find a way to date format the x axis as in autofmt_xddate with that example.

Comment: Could you post what you've tried using `host_subplot` and `axisartist` following that example?

Comment: What I tried is exactly as the example, except that I DON'T KNOW how to format dates in the x axis.  I tried several ways, none work, now I don't have that code anymore as I tried with the code I posted above.

Comment: Hi @jerome, can you post the first few rows of your `mData`?  It would be helpful to see what kind of dtype it is and how your dates are formatted, and that way people can try to test their solution with your data.